# Decomposition of a symmetric positive definite diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\left[\begin{array}{cc}
Q & 0\\
0 & R
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
A^{T}\\
B^{T}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}
A & B\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
A^TA & A^TB\\
B^TA & B^TB
\end{array}\right]$

where $\left[\begin{array}{cc}
Q & 0\\
0 & R
\end{array}\right]\geq0$ and $Q,R$ are symmetric matrices, then

how do we calculate matrices $A$ and $B$?

Comment: I hope the changes I made make the question more clear

Comment: Am I misunderstanding this? Are $A,B$ square matrices? To me the middle term says they are not but the third term says that they are? Am I being very stupid here?

Comment: @GrahamHesketh: I don't think anything implicitly says that $A,B$ must be square, they just need to have the same number of rows. Supposing $A$ is a $n\times a$ and $B$ is a $n\times b$ matrix, $Q=A^TA$ will be $a\times a$ and $R=B^TB$ will be $b\times b$, while $A^TB$ and $B^TA$ are null matrices of size $a\times b$ and $b\times a$ respectively; this all fits together nicely.

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen, I see that makes sense, cheers. My next question for the OP is then is $a=b$? and if so, can we choose $n=a=b$?

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen, would you agree that $Q=A^TA$ is overly restrictive and not necessarily required?

Comment: @GrahamHesketh: I don't see your point; $Q=A^T A$ is an immediate consequence of the first equality, the one that introduces $A,B$.

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen, apologies if I am being stupid but I don't see that, I have updated my answer below to reflect why I think that is not the case.

Comment: @GrahamHesketh: It may be a question of interpretation. When one writes $\binom{P~Q}{R~S}=\binom XY\cdot(A~B)$ as block matrix equation, then I think it may be safely assumed that the blocks were meant to be of compatible sizes left and right, so that $P=XA$, $Q=XB$ etc. If that were _not_ the intention of the question, one could have just written $\binom{Q~0}{0~R}=X^T X$, without splitting up $X=(A~B)$. But given such $X$ (and assuming $Q,R$ both square), there is always exactly one way to split it up into $A,B$ compatible with the sizes of $Q,R$, and we get the question as it is now.

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality assign the matrices the following dimensions: $$Q\in {\rm M}(q,q,\mathbb{C}),\quad R\in {\rm M}(r,r,\mathbb{C}),\quad A\in {\rm M}(n,a,\mathbb{C}),\quad B\in {\rm M}(n,b,\mathbb{C})$$
where we noted that if $Q,R$ are symmetric they are square. Furthermore, if:
$$P=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
Q & 0\\
0 & R
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
A^{T}\\
B^{T}\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
A & B\end{array}\right)\tag{1}$$
then: $$q+r=a+b \tag{2}$$
Next we will prove the existence of a solution and show how one may be found under the assumption that:
$$n\ge q+r=a+b \tag{3}$$
*Lemma:* For every square symmetric matrix $P\in {\rm M}(q+r,q+r,\mathbb{C})$, $\exists M\in {\rm M}(q+r,q+r,\mathbb{C})$ such that: $$P=M^TM \tag{4}$$
*Proof of $(4)$:* every symmetric matrix is diagonalizable by an orthogonal transformation:
\begin{aligned}
P&=SDS^T\\
&=S\sqrt{D}\left(\sqrt{D}\right)^TS^T\\
&=S\sqrt{D}\left(S\sqrt{D}\right)^T
\end{aligned}
and thus we may chose:
$$M=\left(S\sqrt{D}\right)^T\tag{5}$$
where $D$ is the diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of $P$, and $S$ is the square matrix containing the associated eigenvectors.

To complete the proof that a solution exists we note that we may chose:
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
A & B\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
M\\
O\end{array}\right)\tag{6}$$
where $O\in {\rm M}(n-a-b,a+b,\mathbb{C})$ is the empty matrix. To fit the square matrix $M$ into $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
A & B\end{array}\right)$ we needed to assume $(3)$, but without $(3)$ a solution may not exist anyway on the basis that there are not enough degrees of freedom to solve the general case. We also add that although existence has been shown uniqueness has not.

Next we note that the block diagonal form of $P$ simplifies finding $M$ as we may assume the same block diagonal structure for $M$ and write:
$$M=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
N & 0\\
0 & K
\end{array}\right)$$
$$P=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
Q & 0\\
0 & R
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
N^TN & 0\\
0 & K^TK
\end{array}\right)$$
then solve:
$$Q=N^TN,\quad R=K^TK$$
following the procedure in $(3)$.

**Example**

Here is an example I tested this method on:
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
Q & 0\\
0 & R
\end{array}\right]= \left[ \begin {array}{cccc}  1.0& 2.0& 0.0& 0.0\\ 
 2.0& 5.0& 0.0& 0.0\\  0.0& 0.0& 2.0& 4.0
\\ 0.0& 0.0& 4.0& 7.0\end {array} \right],S= \left[ \begin {array}{cccc}  \cos{\theta}& \sin{\theta}& 0.0& 0.0\\ 
 -\sin{\theta}& \cos{\theta}& 0.0& 0.0\\  0.0& 0.0& \cos{\phi}& \sin{\phi}
\\ 0.0& 0.0& -\sin{\phi}& \cos{\phi}\end {array} \right]$$
I then used $S$ to diagonalize $Q,R$ by solving for $\theta,\phi$ and ultimately found that I could choose: $$n=4,\quad a=q=2,\quad b=r=2$$
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
A & B\end{array}\right)=\left[ \begin {array}{cccc}  0.3826834320&- 0.1585126677& 0.0& 0.0
\\  0.9238795327& 2.230442497& 0.0& 0.0
\\  0.0& 0.0& 0.4074281149\,i&- 0.2258160717\,i
\\  0.0& 0.0& 1.471732879& 2.655370577\end {array}
 \right] $$
$$A=\left[ \begin {array}{cc}  0.3826834320&- 0.1585126677
\\  0.9238795327& 2.230442497
\\  0.0& 0.0
\\  0.0& 0.0\end {array}
 \right] ,\quad B=\left[ \begin {array}{cc}  0.0& 0.0
\\  0.0& 0.0
\\  0.4074281149\,i&- 0.2258160717\,i
\\  1.471732879& 2.655370577\end {array}
 \right]$$
which gives: $$A^TA=Q,\quad B^TB=R,\quad A^TB=B^TA=0$$
but also that I could just as easily choose:
$$n=6,\quad a=1,\quad b=3$$
$$A= \left[ \begin {array}{c}  0.3826834320\\ 
 0.9238795327\\ 0\\ 0
\\ 0\\ 0\end {array} \right],\quad B=  \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} - 0.1585126677&0&0\\ 
 2.230442497&0&0\\ 0& 0.4074281149\,i&- 0.2258160717
\,i\\ 0& 1.471732879& 2.655370577
\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0\end {array}
 \right] $$
which gives:
$$\color{green}{A^TA},\quad \color{blue}{ B^TB}, \quad \color{red}{A^TB}, \quad \color{orange}{B^TA}$$
$$\left[ \begin {array}{cccc}  \color{green}{1.0}& \color{red}{2.0}& \color{red}{0.0}& \color{red}{0.0}\\ 
 \color{orange}{2.0}& \color{blue}{5.0}& \color{blue}{0.0}& \color{blue}{0.0}\\  \color{orange}{0.0}& \color{blue}{0.0}& \color{blue}{2.0}& \color{blue}{4.0}
\\ \color{orange}{0.0}& \color{blue}{0.0}& \color{blue}{4.0}& \color{blue}{7.0}\end {array} \right]$$

Answer (score 2):

For generic $Q,R$ this will not be possible at all: for example, when $Q,R$ have full rank, $A,B$ must have full rank, and then $A^tB$ and $B^tA$ cannot be $0$. Similarly, in fact, if *either* has full rank, this is impossible unless the other is $0$.

Indeed, the rank of $\pmatrix{A\cr B}$ is at most the number of columns, which is the number of columns of $A$ (and/or $B$). Thus, to allow $A^tB=0$, the columns of $A$ must all be orthogonal to the columns of $B$. The severe constraint this puts on $Q,R$ can be expressed in a variety of ways.